# Why did Dumbledore move the mirror to the chamber where the Philosopher's Stone was?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-philosophers-stone

If Harry saw his parents in the mirror and Ron saw himself holding the Quidditch cup, it could be a useful mirror. But Dumbledore had told Harry:

> "it will be moved to another location and you must not go looking for it again."

Harry asked Dumbledore what it shows and Dumbledore said:

> "it shows the deepest desire of our hearts"

So later in the movie when Harry, Ron and Hermione take a huge risky rescue mission to prevent Snape from getting the stone, Harry goes on after Hermione stays behind to help a knocked out Ron on the wizard's chess.

So Harry went forward to find Quirrell in the chamber...and the mirror that Quirrell tried using to get the stone.

My main question is:

**Why, when it was suspected that someone was trying to break in to steal the stone, that Dumbledore had moved the valuable mirror to there in particular?**

It makes  no sense to me as Dumbledore was supposed to be the greatest wizard alive at the time.

*So why did he do it?*

Comment: The question title and the bold version below seem slightly different to me. Are you asking why the mirror (which contained the stone) was moved to *that* chamber rather than another location in, or outside, the castle?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## The stone was *inside* the mirror; the mirror was an added layer of protection for the Stone.

The mirror was in fact the *only* part of the defenses that posed any real trouble for Quirrell; this is evident from what we see in the book:

> "Now, wait quietly, Potter. I need to examine this interesting mirror."
> It was only then that Harry realized what was standing behind Quirrell.
> It was the Mirror of Erised.
> "This mirror is the key to finding the Stone," Quirrell murmured,
> tapping his way around the frame. "Trust Dumbledore to come up with
> something like this... but he's in London... I'll be far away by the
> time he gets back...."
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's/Philosopher's Stone*, chapter 17: "The Man With Two Faces"</sub>

The Mirror of Erised is itself the final defense for the Stone. The Stone was hidden inside the mirror in such a way that only one who didn't want to actually *use* the Stone could get it; it was moved to where the Stone was because it was helping to guard the stone.

Answer (score 0):

You could also argue that the entire thing was a set up. Why bother with solutions for each safe guard? Three first year students got past them all. It's either incredibly irresponsible to have done this, or part of a bigger plan.

Comment: It just so happens that each of the three obstacles that you have to get past alive to get to the philosophers stone was that: one obstacle was set up so each represented the biggest skill of all Ron Hermione and Harry.

Comment: Hermione: *Devils snare*, Harry: *Flying keys*, Ron:  *Wizards Chess*